# Design a PowerBI dataset architecture for a report refresh time under 5 seconds

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

New development where the client wants to refresh a set of reports in under 5 seconds with multiple granularities from a 100 GB dataset via delta table as the primary source. I will have about 10 fact tables which would need to be refreshed daily and about 40 dimension tables of which 10 are to be refreshed daily.

For a refresh to happen, i understand that we have to create partitions and set up an incremental refresh of the dataset.

Here are my few queries

1. The client wants to refresh the report in under 5 seconds. What is the approach i need to take? I currently am planning with one of 3 options but unable to decide the best.

**Option 1**
Have a Dataset pull data from the delta tables and connect all the reports to this data set using a live connection

**EXAMPLE**
DeltaTable IMPORTMODE Dataset A  to Report 1 via LIVE CONNECTION
DeltaTable IMPORTMODE Dataset A to Report 2 via LIVE CONNECTION
DeltaTable IMPORTMODE Dataset A to Report 3 via LIVE CONNECTION

The issue in the above approach is that this dataset would be a single Point Of Failure or it could be the single Point Of Truth, because the data set being huge in size refresh times would increase multifold.

**Option 2 **

Have a data set pull the data from the delta tables and then have reports built. The reports will have their own individual data sets and I will connect the reports to this data set using an import mode.

This satisfy the customers requirement of having the reports refresh in under 5 seconds

**EXAMPLE**

1. DeltaTable IMPORTMODE Dataset A to Dataset 1 IMPORTMODE Report 1
2. DeltaTable IMPORTMODE Dataset A to Dataset 2 IMPORTMODE Report 2
3. DeltaTable IMPORTMODE Dataset A to Dataset 3 IMPORTMODE Report 3

The issue with the above example is I will first have to process Dataset A which will have data up to 100 GB and post processing of this data set; I'll will move on to process individual data sets 1, 2 and 3 in a parallel mode. The issue with this approach is that between datasets 1, 2 and 3, there maybe a chance that the same table maybe getting process multiple Times with different relationships and this may lead to delay in Data Refresh Times.

**Option 3**
Have a data set pull the data from the delta tables and then have reports built. The reports will have their own 2 datasets and I will connect the reports to this data set using an Live Connection. The data set would be designed based on the levels of granularity required in the report.

2. Incremental refresh is an option on the dataset, but how do I perform a full refresh of the whole dataset once a month - refresh the dataset for a whole 3 years.
3. Do I have to create a job or a PowerAutomate flow to perform a full refresh of a dataset via XMLA or REST APIs?

Any help that could be provided by the architects on the forum would be greatly appreciated as I am stuck in a dilemma.

this is a initial stages of the project and I am currently contemplating the right approach to take to design the best architecture that would enable the client to view the report in under 5 seconds